# "Do you have any idea who you're talking to?"

Tags: questions, inversion, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives

I've got caught up in a discussion about this particular sentence from new season of The Walking Dead on non-English forum. No one seems to know why *are* appears after *you*.

My guess is that it's dependent clause (this is why I'm adding such tag), but I'm not sure because it's the first time I'm reading about it. People on the forum mentioned:

- Spoken English
- Silly Americans

So, my question: Why is *are* appears after *you* and not before as many people on the forum expected?

Comment: Related: 1. [Long subjects in indirect questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55734/long-subjects-in-indirect-questions/55739#55739) 2. [Alternative to Indirect Questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34173/alternative-to-indirect-questions?lq=1) 3. [Why do we put the verb to be at the end of these questions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61714/why-do-we-put-the-verb-to-be-at-the-end-of-these-questions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing subject and verb positions in statements and questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/changing-subject-and-verb-positions-in-statements-and-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We invert the verb (or auxiliary) and subject in a direct question:

> **I am** Colin.
>
> Who **am I**?
>
> **They want** a meal.
>
> What **do they** want?

But when the question is embedded in another clause, the inversion does not happen:

> You know who **I am**.
>
> I will ask what **they want**.

This is absolutely standard in English. (For some speakers this is the only possible form, but for some speakers sentences like *I will ask what do they want* are also grammatical).

If you want to know *why*, that is not a kind of question that can usually be answered; but for part of the answer, note that English likes to keep the verb in second position in a clause.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It could be argued that the sentence, *I will ask what do they want* should really be written,  *I will ask, What do they want?* or similar

Comment: We invert the verb and the subject in a direct question? Invert we really the verb and the subject in a direct question?

Comment: I said "the verb (or auxiliary)". I did not feel it necessary to point out the detail that in Modern English normal verbs do not invert with their subjects and require an auxiliary as stunt-man.

Comment: @Araucaria, The formulation, "We invert the verb and the subject in a direct question?" is relatively recent and possibly came about through the influence of Spanish. It is simply tacking a question mark onto the end of an ordinary statement. The real 'English' version would be, "Do we invert the verb and the subject in a direct question?" and that follows the rule.

Comment: Ah. I missed the import of the first sentence of @Araucaria's comment. You are right: in a _canonical_ (or traditional) direct question. Not that it affects the part of my answer which bears directly on the question.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK That, it would seem would be a case of inverting a dummy auxiliary and a subject - the necessity of the dummy here is precisely because we must have an auxiliary for the inversion, we cannot use a lexical verb.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, agreed. Like the stuntman, am going to nick that for my classes.

Comment: @Araucaria - That's simply another aspect of the evolution of the language. At one time it would have been grammatically acceptable to ask, "Invert we the verb and the subject in a direct question?"

Comment: P.S. Couldn't let it go without an example: " I pray, good master, what mean you by a leather-mouthed fish?"  The Complete Angler ... Edited by James Rennie, Izaak Walton January 1, 1833  https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RBhdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA77&dq=%22what+mean+you+by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBGoVChMIxc7D84XbyAIVTGkUCh1cNQeI#v=onepage&q=%22what%20mean%20you%20by%22&f=false